# Create generic controller with spring

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-restcontroller

I created this structure of code. it's more and less generic.

I search to write more generic code.

all my controller should have a save, get, getById

How to have a more generic controller?, 
how to pass service object, do i need to pass

for other layer, if you think that could be more generic... don't hesitage

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
@RestController
public class CardsRestController extends BaseController {

    private final CardsService cardsService;

    @Autowired
    public CardsRestController(final CardsService cardsService) {
        this.CardsService = cardsService;
    }

     @GetMapping(value = "/cards")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<CardsDto>> getCards(Pageable page) {

        if (page == null) {
            page = getDefaultPageRequest();
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(cardsService.getCards(page), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/cards/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<CardsDto> getCardsById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

        CardsDto Cards = cardsService.getCardsById(id);

        return Cards != null
                ? new ResponseEntity(Cards, HttpStatus.OK)
                : new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}


public abstract class BaseController {

    protected PageRequest getDefaultPageRequest() {
        return PageRequest.of(0, 20);
    }

}



public interface CardsService {
    public void saveCards(CardsDto cardDto);
    public Page<CardsDto> customSearch(CardSearch CardSearch, Pageable page);
    public Page<CardsDto> getCards(Pageable page);
    public CardsDto getCardsById(Integer id);
}


public class CardsServiceImpl extends BaseService<Cards, CardsDto> implements CardsService {

    @Autowired
    public CardsServiceImpl(CardsRepository cardsRepository) {
        super(Cards.class);
        this.cardsRepository = cardsRepository;
    }

    public CardsRepository cardsRepository;

    @Override
    public void saveCards(CardsDto cardDto) {
            save(cardDto);
    }

}

public abstract class BaseService<T, R extends BaseDto> {
    private JpaRepository<T, Integer> repository;
    private final Class< T> clsT;
    public BaseService(Class<T> clsT) {
        this.clsT = clsT;
    }

    public Page<R> get(Pageable page, JpaRepository<T, Integer> repository, Function<T, R> convert) {
        Page<T> pageR = repository.findAll(page);
        List<R> dtos = convertsToDto(pageR.getContent(), convert);
        return new PageImpl<>(dtos, page, pageR.getTotalElements());
    }

    public R getById(Integer id, Function<T, R> convert){
         Optional<T> beans = repository.findById(id);

        if (beans.isPresent()) {
            return convert.apply(beans.get());
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public interface CardsRepository extends JpaRepository<Cards, Integer>, CardsRepositoryCustom {
}

public interface CardsRepositoryCustom {
}

@Repository
public class CardsRepositoryImpl  extends SimpleJpaRepository implements CardsRepositoryCustom{

     @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    public CardsRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
        super(Cards.class, em);
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: You can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016663/generic-controller-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look into Spring Data Rest that may help you generalize your code a little more effectively.

https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/